# Migrate Wix Project to version 4.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wix, migration, wix4

I recently ugraded Wix to Version 4.0.

After updating the namespaces Visual Studio (2015) won't recognize these new ones.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Product Id="*" Name="_any_name" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Anyone" UpgradeCode="8c568038-54cf-43ff-aa2c-581f4dd0aea0" Codepage="1252">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="_any_title" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="group_ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <Property Id="pro_SetupExe" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <CustomAction Id="ca_LaunchSetupExe" Property="pro_SetupExe" ExeCommand="/FORCE_HIDE_FIRST_RUN /UNATTENDED_INSTALL /AUTOACCEPT_ALL /FORCE_CLOSE_WHEN_DONE /ON_REBOOT_MESSAGE:”NO”" Execute="commit" />
    <CustomAction Id="ca_SetSetupPath" Property="pro_SetupExe" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]x64ATIDriver\setup.exe" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="ca_SetSetupPath" Before="ca_LaunchSetupExe" />
        <Custom Action="ca_LaunchSetupExe" Before="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="TempFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

> The Wix element has an incorrect namespace of 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs'.  Please make the Wix element look like the following: Wix xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"

I founde these: [Migrate Wix Project to v4.0 instructions](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/4561-migrate-v3-source-code-to-v4/)

But I don't get what this means:

> Fix: Explicitly set absent Id attributes on File element to the Name attribute or filename from the Source attribute.

So currently I just have the kind of "crashed" project and can't build.

I'd really appreciate some help.

regards Muffex

Comment: Please add your code for the first issue. The second means you need to define the id attribute the same as the name attribute in the file element.

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace error makes it sound like the project is still being built by WiX v3. Also, that migrate to v4 page that you found is for the WixCop tool which automates everything you found there.  It's in the bin directory of the WiX installation directory.

Comment: Well, as far as I do not need any of the new features of Wix 4.0, I reinstalled the old version (v3.10). IMHO the wixcop.exe has quite little documentation. Thanks for your answer. :)