# Error CNDL0199 : The Wix element has an incorrect namespace of 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi'

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

I migrated my WIX project from V2 to V4 and then changed the namespace in the .WXS files

I replaced the below namespace

`<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi">`

with

`<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">`

Once the changes have been made when i run the build installer i am getting the below error:

```
error CNDL0199 : The Wix element has an incorrect namespace of
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2003/01/wi'.  Please make the Wix element
look like the following: <Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
E:\Code\EMR\Wix\src\EMR_Registry_entries.wx
```

I replaced the new namespace but it is not reflecting. Once i run the build installer it is setting with the old namespace. I tried multiple times but it is always setting the old namespace.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **UPDATE**: Question that came up from a second read of your question.
>
> ***Source Control***: "***`Once I run the build installer it is setting with the old namespace.`***" - are you sure the build process doesn't
>   auto-magically ***`1)`*** **`check the WiX source out of your source control system`**? Or ***`2)`*** maybe it is doing some **`XML manipulation via the automation script`**?

---

***WiX Version***: Are you sure you are compiling with **`WiX 4`**? Maybe you are compiling with **`WiX 2`** or **`WiX 3`** unintentionally? Try hard coding the full path to the WiX binary in your build system - if you have one. Please see this (Sean is a WiX developer): [Migrate Wix Project to version 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35888945/migrate-wix-project-to-version-4-0). ***`Frankly I am not sure how well WiX handles multiple-version installations on the same box combined with migrated sources`*** (identically named binaries of different versions - WiX 2, 3, 4 -  globally applicable via the PATH variable? Not sure).

***Visual Studio / Cmd.exe?***: Are you compiling with Visual Studio or via the command line? (I am not quite sure reading your question). Maybe [try via the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481391/129130) (towards bottom) if you are using Visual Studio - or vice versa. Make sure you use the correct WiX binaries (in other words **`WiX 4`**).

***Linked Files?***: I don't have any **`WiX 2`** sources to migrate, but I am wondering if you have several source files that are interconnected. Was that even possible in **`WiX 2`**? I can't remember. In either case, I would make sure you have updated all WiX source files that are pulled in during the build process. Please read the log carefully. Maybe try to compile them with **`Candle.exe`** directly using the command line (**`cmd.exe`** instead of **`Visual Studio`**) to see if the file compiles OK.

***Source Files?***: If it still does not work, please put the source file online so we can have a peek. Github.com for example. A quick look at the source (the real McCoy) goes a long way sometimes - and sometimes it doesn't help at all. Maybe give it a go. **Redacted sources** are just fine - encouraged even. Please pay close attention to sensitive data: [How do I avoid distributing sensitive information in my MSI by accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311010/how-do-i-avoid-distributing-sensitive-information-in-my-msi-by-accident) (and this also goes for published source files - obviously - not just the compiled MSI and its helper files - such as silent installation template batch files).

---

> ***In summary***: That became a lot of babble. Maybe first try to compile the migrated WiX source with the right WiX 4 binaries to
>   determine if that works or not. Then work backwards to figure out what
>   happens during the build process.

Comment: Yes, you are correct the file EMR_Registry_entries.wxs is auto generating from build.xml when i run the build installer from command line. So whatever changes we made in this file it is not taking. So what i have done is, from C# code i am loading this file and then updating. Then this C# .exe, i am using in the Build.xml and with this it is properly updating.